# OpsHub Migration utility unable to do user mapping

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I receive the following error with refreshing the user mapping screen.

```
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
Unable to communicate with the required process opshubtfsservice. Because it is probably not running. Restart application and try again.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I did verify that indeed the service was not running.  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Unlike to the downvoters I had the same question, and this Q and A solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can start the "OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility" service from "Computer Management\Service" manually and then click the "Reload" button on user mapping screen.

Answer (score 0):

The OVMSU tool relies on a background process 'opshubtfsservice' which runs on port 9090. Do you have any other application that would occupy that particular port?  If so, you'll have to keep that program closing whilst the OVSMU tool is running.

You can verify this by running **netstat -aon | findstr "9090"** in command prompt when the migration is NOT running and see if any process do show up in the output. That should give you an idea.